# update a column of a table row sql

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

http://upload7.ir/images/38494239720146662835.png

In this picture I want to read the first line by a query and change the HASDATA to the 1 or true(for first line) but all the hasdata in all lines changes to true.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[selecfirstvalue] (@ParentId int,@CrawlerCheck bigint)
as
select CatId, Title, ParentId, Url, CrawlerCheck from TBLCrowler 
update TBLCrowler set ParentId=@ParentId , CrawlerCheck=@CrawlerCheck , HasData=1 where CatId=CatId
end
```

Here is my c# code:

```
IDataReader get = ClassBase.EReader("selecfirstvalue", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, new SqlParameter[]
{
new SqlParameter("@ParentId",ParentId),
new SqlParameter("@CrawlerCheck",CrawlerCheck)
});
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [update a column of a table row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565091/update-a-column-of-a-table-row)

Comment: `CatId=CatId` makes no sense. It will always eval to true, for each row.Perhaps you would want to manually pass the CatId of the first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the first row exactly? And how do you determine the first row? If it is based on the min CatId val, use something in the lines of

```
update TBLCrowler set ParentId=@ParentId , CrawlerCheck=@CrawlerCheck , HasData=1 
          where CatId=(Select min(CatId) from TBLCrowler)
```

Comment: I used this code and it works, but when this code run in a while ring query still working on the same line. I want to run query in the next line when code is runing in a while ring.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you elaborate?